# How to add an alias to a method in a Dart class?

Tags: dart, methods, alias

How can you add an alias to a method in a Dart class? For example, suppose we have a class `Foo` with method `bar`, and we want `foo.qux(...)` to behave exactly the same as `foo.bar(...)` (where `foo` is an instance of `Foo`), so that `qux` is an alias to `bar`, you can use different names for the same underlying method.

---

I use aliases when a base class/interface declares "generic" method and the subclass overrides with a more specific version that deserves its own name because it provides a stricter contract (even though it can still be accessed through the base name). For example: `BaseMeeting` declares the abstract method `Duration estimateDuration()`, `FutureMeeting` implements it by providing an estimate and `PastMeeting` implements it by providing the actual recorded duration. For users of `PastMeeting`, it makes sense to have an alias `exactDuration()` that points to `estimateDuration()` (or vice-versa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late final field can be used:

```dart
class Foo {
  void bar(Object x) => print(x);
  
  late final qux = bar;
}
```

Type inference allows us to omit the method's signature while preserving type safety.

The only drawback I see is that an IDE's autocompletion might not work exactly the same as with a regular method.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I recommend that you usually don't create aliases to methods.  Using multiple names for the same thing typically is confusing.

If it's for a class you control and you decide that you don't like an old method name, just rename it.  If the class is used by other people, then it might be appropriate to rename the method and to additionally provide a deprecated alias for the old name:

```dart
class Foo {
  void methodWithNewName() {
    // ...
  }

  @Deprecated('Use methodWithNewName instead')
  late final methodWithOldName = methodWithNewName;
}
```

If it's for a class you don't control (perhaps the author picked a particularly bad or misleading name), then you can create an extension that supplies a getter:

```dart
extension FooAliases on Foo {
  void Function() get methodWithNewName => methodWithOldName;
}
```

Comment: I use aliases when a base class/interface declares "generic" method and the subclass overrides with a more specific version that deserves its own name because it provides a stricter contract (even though it can still be accessed through the base name). For example: `BaseMeeting` declares the abstract method `Duration estimateDuration()`, `FutureMeeting` implements it by providing an estimate and `PastMeeting` implements it by providing the actual recorded duration. For users of `PastMeeting`, it makes sense to have an alias `exactDuration()` that points to `estimateDuration()` (or vice-versa).